# How can I customize Eclipse About dialog's about text?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, eclipse-rcp, jdialog

I am trying to reuse Eclipse's About dialog in my application. What I need to do is to add image, hyperlinks, and image links in aboutText, but it seems only hyperlinks are possible in aboutText? Is there a way to add images/image links without providing my own About dialog implementation?

thanks,

Comment: If the code I supplied works the way you desired, consider it as an accepted answer by clicking it.

Comment: Is that Eclipse RCP application?

Comment: Yes, its a Eclipse RCP application. It seems aboutText does not have any option to add images/images links, or perspective name/icon when perspective changes.

Answer (score 4):

Use `JDialog`. You can add `JPanel` object(s) inside it. You are able to put images, hyperlinks, text, labels into JPanel. So it should be trivial.

Take a look at this code snippet and test it. You can refer to external image URLs using HTML tags as well. Check out this line:

```
creditsLabel.setText( "<HTML><IMG SRC=\"http://siesbilkent.appspot.com/images/admin.png\"></IMG></HTML>" );
```

Sample code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyDialog extends JDialog
{
    private JLabel creditsLabel;

    public MyDialog ( JFrame frame )
    {
        super( frame, "Credits", true );
        JPanel panel = new JPanel( new FlowLayout() );
        panel.setBackground( new Color( 255, 0, 128 ) );
        creditsLabel = new JLabel();
        creditsLabel.setText( "<HTML><IMG SRC=\"http://siesbilkent.appspot.com/images/admin.png\"></IMG></HTML>" );
        panel.add( creditsLabel );

        this.getContentPane().add( panel );
        this.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 240, 160 ) );
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        this.setResizable( false );
    }

    public static void main ( String [] args )
    {
        MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog( new JFrame() );
        dialog.setModal( true );
        dialog.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I was talking about reusing/configuring Eclipse IDE's about dialog's aboutText without creating my own dialog. SWT should be used instead of Swing if I have to override Eclipse's AboutDialog, but it is not my option currently.

Comment: Sorry, just saw JDialog/Swing tags were added in my question, I did not intend to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to customize eclipse based application/product then check out this [manual](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/product_configproduct.htm). There are three files that control the branding: `about.ini`, `about.properties` and `about.html`. You can probably use `about.html` for your image links.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. It seems about.html is not for image links on the initial page: "Every feature and plug-in should include an about.html file. This is a simple HTML file that is displayed when the user opens the Eclipse About dialog, opens the Plug-in Details dialog, selects a plug-in, and then clicks the More Info button"